# Using AutoMapper inside a static class in .NET Core 3 with C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I am in a situation where I am shifting some logic from a layer in an extension method class. Problem is that I want to use auto mapper in that Static class having extension methods. The project is running on .NET Core, I am not able to get access to AutoMapper in the static class, like in the controller classes normally we use the constructor to inject the AutoMapper, but static classes do not have constructors.

Is there any way to call the AutoMapper service that is already configured in the `Startup.cs`, in a static class in any way?

Comment: Static classes do have constructors -- `static` ones. However, using them for anything non-trivial that could possibly fail is not recommended, because it's almost impossible to confidently predict when exactly a static constructor will run, and thus error handling becomes a massive pain. If your class has a dependency on Automapper, you should make this explicit -- expose a method to initialize things that `Startup.cs` should call before the extension methods can be used. If you're really kind, have the methods detect when this hasn't been done to give a sensible error.

Comment: You may consider using a Singleton service instead of a static class then you can inject IMapper instance on the service.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you fir the insight and valuable input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you need to use AutoMapper within a static method you only have two possibilities:

1. Give AutoMapper as additional argument into your static method.
2. Create a mapper on-the-fly for the desired Profile.

While the first one is quite self-explanory, the second one needs an additional helper method, that makes it easier to use:

```
using System;

namespace AutoMapper
{
    public static class WithProfile<TProfile> where TProfile : Profile, new()
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<IMapper> MapperFactory = new Lazy<IMapper>(() =>
        {
            var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(config => config.AddProfile<TProfile>());
            return new Mapper(mapperConfig, ServiceCtor ?? mapperConfig.ServiceCtor);
        });

        public static IMapper Mapper => MapperFactory.Value;

        public static Func<Type, object> ServiceCtor { get; set; }

        public static TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<TDestination>(source);
        }
    }
}
```

With this available you got a static method, that can be used as follows:

```
var dest = WithProfile<MyProfile>.Map<Destination>(source);
```

But be aware that this second approach is quite heavy and depending on the amount of time the method will be called you should better use the first approach.

Comment: Good Day Oliver , I went with the first approach as I wanted to avoid creating Profiles dynamically and relied on the as I wanted to stay on track of implementing the API's itself. Nevertheless, your second option is very interesting , I'll try to have try running some unit test cases around your second implementation. Thank you very much for the answer.